# Elementary number theory equation simplification

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $x\equiv 2 \pmod 5$

first congruence gives $x=1+3k$, substituting this second congruence we get

$1+3k \equiv 2 \pmod 5$...(I), consequently $k \equiv 2 \pmod 5$...(II)

can someone tell how we reach from (I) to (II) ? which rules are applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3k\equiv 1\equiv 6\pmod{5}\stackrel{:3}\iff k\equiv 2\pmod{5}$$

Or apply [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find $s,t\in\mathbb Z$ such that $3s+5t=1$, in which case $3s\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so $k\equiv s\pmod{5}$.

Subtract consecutive equations:

$$5=3(0)+5(1)\\3=3(1)+5(0)\\2=3(-1)+5(1)\\1=3(2)+5(-1)$$

Therefore $3(2)\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so $k\equiv 2\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $1 + 3k \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, we also have $3k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. Now $3^{-1} = 2$ by inspection; multiplying both sides by $2$ gives the desired result.

Comment: i didn't get what do you mean by  $3^{-1}=2$?

Comment: @Vikram The multiplicative inverse of $3$ is $2$; that is, $3 \times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

$1+3k=2$ or $3k=1$

There are so few numbers to check, so this is easiest:

$3k$ (mod 5) for k=0,1,2,3,4 all (mod 5):

$3*0=0$

$3*1=1$

$3*2=6=1$

$3*3=9=4$

$3*4=12=2$

$k=1$ is the only one that works (mod 5).